# Why this code is giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c++14, binary-search

> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the leaderboard and wants to track her ranking. Its leaderboard works like this:
>
> -The player with the highest score is ranked number  on the leaderboard.
>
> -Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.
>
> For example, the four players on the leaderboard have high scores of 100, 90, 90 and 80. Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2 and 3 respectively. If Alice's scores are 70, 80 and 105 her rankings after each game are 4th, 3rd and 1st.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


struct table{
    int rank;
    int score;
};
```

> This is a modified binary search function iplementation for searching the score.

```
int search(vector<table> v,int low,int high,int n,int x){
    if(low<=high){
        int mid =(high+low)/2;
        if((v[mid].score==x) || (mid==0 && v[mid].score<x))
            return v[mid].rank;
        if(mid==n-1 && v[mid].score>x)
            return (v[mid].rank + 1);
        if(v[mid].score>x && x>v[mid+1].score && mid<n-1)
            return v[mid+1].rank;
        if(v[mid].score>x)
            return search(v,mid+1,high,n,x);
        else
            return search(v,low,mid-1,n,x);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

> Main climbingLeaderboard function

```
vector<int> climbingLeaderboard(vector<int> scores, vector<int> alice) {
    vector<table> v;
    vector<int> res;
    int n = scores.size();
    int m = alice.size();
    int x=1;
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        if(scores[i]!=scores[i-1] && i>0)
            x++;

        v[i].rank = x;
        v[i].score = scores[i];
    }
    int z;
    for(int i=0 ; i<m ; i++){
        x=alice[i];
        z = search(v,0,n-1,n,x);
        res.push_back(z);
    }
    return res;
}
```

> Driver Program

```
int main(){
    int scores_count;
    cin >> scores_count;
    vector<int> scores; `//vector for storing leaderboard scores`
    int k;
    for(int i=0 ; i<scores_count ; i++){
        cin >> k;
        scores.push_back(k);
    }
    int game_count;   `//number of games played by alice`
    vector<int> Alice;  `//vector for storing Alice's scores`
    for(int i=0 ; i<game_count ; i++){
        cin >> k;
        alice.push_back(k);
    }
    vector<int> result; `//vector for storing result rank of each game of Alice`
    result = climbingLeaderboard(scores,alice);
    for(auto i = result.begin() ; i!=result.end() ; i++){
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: In your *climbingLeaderboard* function, the first loop will attempt to access `scores[i-1]` when i is set to 0, resulting in a negative index for a `std::vector` access.

Fix: Change the for loop to start from i=1.

Problem 2: You access `v` by index without instantiating any structures to hold the data (e.g. `v[i].rank = x`).

Fix 2: Create an instance of the structure and write the data to it, then push it back into the vector `v`. Alternatively, reserve the memory for the whole vector as a preallocation.

Problem 3: On closer inspection, your search functionality is definitely broken. You should probably test this in isolation from the rest of the code.

Comment: @RaioSilence The conditional statement is  `if(scores[i]!=scores[i-1] && i>0)` . If `i=0` then the above statement will be false and then it will not be considered going beyond the bound. But I have considered your suggestion but the problem still exists.

Comment: @SundramSharan In order to evaluate the conditional statement, the access would still be attempted. If you want exclude the case where i=0, you must use a nested if structure, checking i>0 as the first condition. I will also check your code further to determine if there are further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Core Dump/Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that does not belong to you.
Error in function:Main climbingLeaderboard function:

Accessing out of array index bounds

Start Loop From I =1 as you are doing score[i-1] which here in the first iteration would score[-1] (index) and there is no -1 index in c++

```
for(int i=1; i<n ; i++){


    if(scores[i]!=scores[i-1] && i>0)
        x++;

    v[i].rank = x;
    v[i].score = scores[i];
}
```